# Back-testing time period

Tags: pine-script

Is there a way in Pine Script to use the number of bars to set the back-testing time period instead of start dates and end dates. The number of bars would equate to the number of years, I.e., 260 bars would equate to one year and 320 bars would equal two years, etc. So the user input to choose the time period would be in terms of years from the present time (or most recent bar). This would be similar to what WallStreet.io does to set the time period back-test period.